# How do I change the field validator in Angular 5 when it's INVALID but it's really VALID?

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material2

So, I have code that is for a USER FORM.

The PHONE NUMBER is masked coming from NODE like so:

```
   module.exports = ({
      props
    }) => {
      const phone =  props.phoneNumber;
      if (phone) {
        const prefix = phone.substr(1, 1);
        const suffix = phone.substr(phone.length - 3);
        const masking = '******';
        const fullmask = '**********';
        return `${  prefix}${  masking}${  suffix}`;
      }
      return `${  fullmask}`;
    };
```

When the form opens, it's:

1) NOT DIRTY
2) NOT TOUCHED
3) NOT VALID due to PHONE NUMBER FIELD being INVALID

The following is in the DEV Console for PHONE NUMBER

[image]

this is the code I'm using to TRY and FORCE the phone number field to BE VALID

```
//WE NEED TO MANUALLY CHANGE THESE PROPS for this field
//As its NOT TOUCHED, NOT DIRTY and NOT INVALID out of the gate
if (this.accountForm.controls.phoneNumber.touched === false &&
  this.accountForm.controls.phoneNumber.dirty === false) {
  this.accountForm.controls['phoneNumber'].setErrors({'invalid': false});
  this.accountForm.controls['phoneNumber'].setErrors({'status': 'VALID'});
  this.accountForm.controls['phoneNumber'].valid = true;
}
//Normal ERROR CHECKING once TOUCHED and DIRTY
if (this.accountForm.controls.phoneNumber.touched === true) {
  if (this.accountForm.controls.phoneNumber.dirty === true) {
    if (controlName === 'phoneNumber' &&
      this.accountForm.controls.phoneNumber.invalid === true) {
      result += (`${label} is not in a proper format.`);
      return (result);
    }
  }
}
```

QUESTION: How do I prevent this ONE FIELD from starting out INVALID?  It makes no sense?

NOTE: The 9******251 MASK is required for HIPAA. It's coming in but our EMAIL field is masked the same way and "IS" valid.

We're using ANGULAR 5 and Angular Material 2

Comment: isn't an empty field invalid ? You may check "mandatory" option in the form. Also, your regex makes an empty value "invalid", that's why it is invalid... Why do you want it to be valid so ? is it a not mandatory field ?

Comment: OK, so this is AN UPDATE PAGE. The data coming in has ALREADY been validated and is displaying for the user to VERIFY and only change the field like Phone Number or email or last name should they be married for example.  What I'm saying is, WHY VALIDATE something that's already been entered on SIGN UP and initial SAVE? All I'm trying to do is validate ONLY THOSE FIELD(s) that have been changed and send those FIELD(s) over the wire to the server for UPDATING. If you DO NOT touch anything else, why validate it, why send it, right? Make sense?  During initial load, forms.js is INVALIDATING it.

Comment: Figured it out: Add this to the BUTTON (submit) - [disabled]="accountForm.untouched && accountForm.pristine || processing" --- The PROCESSING is for our case, not normal. --- accountForm is the name of our FORMGROUP.... FYI

Comment: Whoa! You don't have to EMPHASISE your question with CAPS!

Comment: LOL... Sorry about that. Noted for all future processing

Answer (score 0):

The regexp used is probably from INPUT form validation, when user enters data.

Now, during update the number is masked, therefore it contains `*` as you can see in the image.

Modify you validator regexp to `^[2-9]{1}[\*]{6}[0-9]{3}$`